# List/search dart-pub packages

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Does the pub package manager in dart expose a way to list or search through existing pub packages?

This would, for example, make it possible to build alternative platforms for accessing/rating/exploring packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JSON API which allows to fetch all kind of data.
You can use one of these packages or investigate the source to see how the API can be used:

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_client
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_pub_client
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_server

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever on the stability of this API, which prevents any reasonable use in production. Any other options?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: It isn't officially supported or documented in any way.

Comment: But it's the only option.

Comment: This sadly prevents the community to build very useful tools around pub.

Comment: The `pub` command line tool uses this protocol. I doubt the main parts will change in unexpected ways. Some details may change, but it shouldn't be too hard to apply these changes.